# Inline <% f.submit %> styling in a .erb file

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, embedded-ruby

Basically I want the background color of my button to be a darker shade of the form's background color which is determined by the color attribute of the object I'm visiting the 'edit' view of. Currently I'm using

```
<div class="formPageBG" id="formPageBG" style="background-color: <%=@student.color%>">
```

To dynamically set the color of the background upon visit. However, I'm not sure how to access the same in-line style property on my button which is generated by

```
<div class="action">
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
</div>
```

This button is getting styled in CSS through .action:input, but I can't access the @student variable from my CSS sheet. I've looked into a bunch of different ways to try and work around this like passing data to Javascript or using SASS variables from Javascript but I have no idea how to properly get the ruby variables into a CSS sheet. I've resorted to inline styling seeing as it's a .erb file and the variables are already there. I've tried some different syntax like

```
<%= f.submit "Update", style: 'background-color:<%=@student.color%>'%>
<%= f.submit "Update", :style => 'background-color:<%=@student.color%>'}%>
<%= f.submit "Update", {:style => 'background-color:<%=@student.color%>;'}%>
<%= f.submit "Update", {:style => 'background-color:<%=@student.color%>'}%>
```

But those haven't worked. I also tried just copying the HTML that this ruby snippet creates and styling that in-line but that didn't seem to work either (also would have felt sloppy if it did because the rest of my form is generated by form_for). So either I need a way to access the @student variable from my CSS sheet (that would be ideal) or in-line style this button in my .erb file. Also, if I were able to finally style the background-color, any idea how I would be able to dynamically produce a darker shade of that color through CSS? Can I use the filter:contrast or filter:brightness thing with in-line styling?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the variable with - `"#{foo}"` (double quotes, hash and curly brackets), so in you case it would be:

```
<%= f.submit "Update", style: "background-color: #{@student.color} "%>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing:

```
<%= f.submit "Update", style: "background-color: #{ @student.color }", class: "formPageBG",  id: "formPageBG"  %>
```